# What regex flavour does Apache's mod_rewrite use?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Moreover, does it support named capturing groups and backreferences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It uses [Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](http://pcre.org/).  You can pretty much find all the information you are looking for [right here in the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex).  The short answer is yes, it supports both.